# Do you recognize this math font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, eulervm

I have been looking in different sources such as the [Survey of free math fonts](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) but I am not able to recognize which math font is used for typesetting the following formulas appearing in a beamer presentation. Do you have any idea?

[image]

In particular, letters are upright but this may possibly come from a `frenchmath` option.

[EDIT] As correctly guessed in comments, these formulas come from a beamer presentation.

Comment: I think this is a beamer presentation and maybe it's the one on slide 3 or 13 of this file http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/MathFonts.pdf

Comment: It looks like what you get from `\usepackage {eulervm}` and `\usepackage {eufrak}` I think.  At least the symbols, but not perhaps the numerals.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Also the numerals are Euler Math.

Comment: Thanks, it was what I thought but was unable to get the same appearance myself. The problem came from my use of the `iwona` package. It is not solved yet, but at least has nothing to do anymore with this question.

Comment: Do you have access to the PDF? Then you coud take a look into the fonts list.

Comment: @FooBar: I have access to this PDF file, but `pdffonts theFile.pdf` does not give me the Euler font (at least in the lines I understand). 

To anwser my previous question (comment #3), you need to specify the options `mathserif` and `professionalfont` to beamer in order to combine Eulervm and Iwona.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an `euler` font from `eulervm` package:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather*}
        \frac{1120D}{1000I/S} \\
        \frac{2\cdot10^{12}\mathrm{D}}{10^{12}\mathrm{I/S}} \\
        \mathbb{P}(C=k)\sim e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \\
        \frac{\partial F(z,q)}{\partial z} = F(z,q)\cdot\frac{F(qz,q) - qF(z,q)}{q-1} \\
        \int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1} \\
        \pi \\
        s=s_1s_2\dots s_\ell, s_j \in \mathcal{D}, \ell \propto 10^9
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Here's an almost perfect match of the original image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1120D}{1000I/S};\quad
 \frac{2\cdot10^{12}D}{10^{12}I/S}.     \mathbb{P}(C=k)\sim e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}; \\
&\frac{\partial F(z,q)}{\partial z} = F(z,q)\cdot\frac{F(qz,q) - qF(z,q)}{q-1}. \\
&\textcolor{red}{\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}\,dx.}\qquad \pi \\
&\textcolor{red}{s=s_1s_2\dots s_\ell,\qquad
  s_j \in \mathcal{D},\quad \ell \propto 10^9}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `euler` package is not recommended; it's better `\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}`. Please, *never* use `$$` in LaTeX; at least in examples here. `;-)`

Comment: Note that with `\mathrm{D}` and `\mathrm{I/S}`, the letters `D`, `I`, and `S` will be set in `Computer Modern` rather than in `Euler`. Better to omit those `\mathrm` wrappers.